# Como hago para recuperar la variable eMail en Java de esta estructura de datos

Tags: java

Como hago para recuperar la variable eMail en Java de esta estructura de datos. Esta es la estrucutura:
Al hacer un print despliega asi:

```
{
   Telefono =0, eMail=kakaroto@hotmail.com, monto=$54977, 
   Numero Documento=0, Origen de Pago:=Subsidio, 
   Tipo de Pago:=Transferencia , 
   Banco=RABOBANK CHILE, 
   Tipo de Cuenta=CUENTA VISTA, 
   Numero de Cuenta=0003331111
}
```

Comment: Lo que imprimes es un array o que es tu estructura?

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que hace print? Contextualiza un poco mas tu pregunta por favor.

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista tus datos parecen un objeto JSON pero en realidad no lo son. Entonces, para extraer el email puedes recurrir a expresiones regulares, buscando lo que haya entre `eMail=`y `,`:

He editado la pregunta con un programa completo.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/nDnYp5)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class ExtraerEmail
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    String text = "{Telefono =0,eMail=kakaroto@hotmail.com,monto=$54977,Numero Documento=0,Origen de Pago:=Subsidio,Tipo de Pago:=Transferencia,Banco=RABOBANK CHILE,Tipo de Cuenta=CUENTA VISTA,Numero de Cuenta=0003331111}";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("eMail=(.+?),"); //buscar valor entre eMail= y ,
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    matcher.find();
    String sEmail=matcher.group(1); //Extraer cadena encontrada
    System.out.println("Este es el email: "+ sEmail); // Prints String I want to extract    


    }
}
```

**Resultado**

> Este es el email: kakaroto@hotmail.com

---

**@Deprecated**

<s>No es un objeto JSON, ignorar lo que sigue:</s>

Lo que presentas es objeto Json, llamado en Java [JSONObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html). OJo un objeto JSON no es lo mismo que un JSONArray.

Para leer el email sería algo como esto:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
String email = obj.getString("eMail");
```

**Nota:**
Asumo que `str` es la variable que imprimes para que te muestre los valores entre `{}`. Si no es una cadena, sino un JSON en sí, obtienes el email llamando `.getString("eMail")` sobre el nombre de tu objeto Json directamente.

Ver la [ayuda de Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html).

Comment: los JSON usan doble comillas y no llevan los dos puntos ":"

Comment: Cierto lo primero, pero no lo segundo. Los JSON llevan los dos puntos: `{
     "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "age": 25,
     "address" : {
         "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
         "city": "New York",
         "state": "NY",
         "postalCode": "10021"
     }
 }`

Comment: tienes razón me confundí.

Comment: Gracias  a todos por su ayuda el código que me enviaron me sirvio para resolver mi problema muy agradecido.

Comment: @Kakaroto Si el código ha resuelto tu problema marca la respuesta con "resuleto" haciendo clic en la flecha (cotejo) a la izquierda de la pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este codigo, esta todo comentado

```
String text = "{Telefono =0, eMail=kakaroto@hotmail.com, monto=$54977, Numero Documento=0, Origen de Pago:=Subsidio, Tipo de Pago:=Transferencia, Banco=RABOBANK CHILE, Tipo de Cuenta=CUENTA VISTA, Numero de Cuenta=0003331111}";
text = text.replace("{","").replace("}","").replace(":","");    //Limpiamos un poco quitando las llaves y los dos punto
String valorEmail = ""; //inicializamos el string donde se guardará lo que buscas
List<String> datosSeparados = Arrays.asList(text.split(",")); //hacemos un split para separar en una lista cuando encuentre una coma "," 
for(int i=0; i<datosSeparados.size(); i++){ //recorremos los datosSeparados
    List<String> valores = Arrays.asList(datosSeparados.get(i).split("=")); //hacemos un segundo split, para separar el nombre y su valor
    if(valores.get(0).toUpperCase().trim().contains("EMAIL")){  //buscamos el nombre email
        valorEmail= valores.get(1).trim();  //guardamos cuando encuentre email y quitamos espacios al rededor de las comas
    }
}

if(!valorEmail.equals("")){ //preguntamos si valorEmail es distinto al inicial
    Log.d(TAG, "Sí se encontró email, implementa acá lo que deseas hacer");
}
```